# Barcode scanner with WiFI and HTTP/SOAP support

Tags: php, soap, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an application with PHP to speed up the inventory process at warehouse. 
And I'm looking for a barcode scanner that could send HTTP requests to the server (and receive data from it) over Wi-Fi network. I would like to integrate the scanner with my PHP application.

The protocol is not important; it could be SOAP, XML-RPC or just simple HTTP GET request. I just need to receive data (product code and quantity) on the server side and then reply back with some data (product name and processing status).

What can you suggest to me?

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options available for "Mobile Computers" that have barcode scanning features and WiFi connectivity.  And since they are running Windows Mobile, you have lots of options for programming them to suit your specific tasks.

For example, you might look at offerings from [Motorola](http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Handheld+Computers) or [Honeywell](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/category.aspx?category=Mobile%20Computers&cat=HSM).  There are several other players in this space as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Android app **[Barcode Scanner Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.winternet.barcodescannerterminal&hl=en)** (DISCLAIMER! I'm the developer). It scans your barcode and sends it to a webserver over regular HTTP protocol like you are describing.

More details [here](http://www.winternet.no/barcodescannerterminal/).